# Extract filename with Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, filenames

I'm writing a Script wich reads several files line by line, checks each line for file-references and then checks for the existence of these files.

Inside the files I've got strings like this:

`example 1: soundSet = { name = "bus_modern", horn = "vehicle/truck_modern/horn.wav" }
example 2: id = "vehicle/bus/citaro/lod_0_w2.msh",
example 3: "vehicle/bus/berkhof_duvedec/berkhof_duvedec_lod_0_w2.msh", "vehicle/bus/berkhof_duvedec/berkhof_duvedec_lod_0_w3.msh",`

So I need to extract somehow the filename from the strings.
My current attempt was to remove all whitespace from the string, cut the first part including the "-char and chop off everything after the second "-char.

This obviously doesn't work well with example 1 and 3:
In example 1 I've got my file-reference in the second part of my string, in example 3 I've got two files to extract.

No I'm quite stumped, how can I extract any file reference from a given string?

```
    open $filehandle, "<", $file or die "can't open $file\n";

    # read the whole file and check for references
    while (<$filehandle>)
    {
        my $line=$_;
        my $count=0;
       $count++ while ($line =~ m/\//g);
       # looks like we found a file-reference
        if ( $count > 1) 
        { 
           # remove all whitespace now

            # prefix whitespace
            $line =~ s/^\s+//;

            # suffix whitespace
            $line =~ ~ s/\s+$//;

            # intermediate whitespace
            $line=~ s/ //g;

            # cut until "
            $line=~ s/[^\"]*\"//;
            pdebug (2, "    rem-pre-\": $line \n");

            # chop off all chars after "
            my $oper = index($line, '"');
            my $word = substr($line, 0, $oper);
            $line=$word;


            # putting it together
            my $searchfile=buildpath($line);
            if ( -e $searchfile )
            {
                pdebug(1,"found\n");
            }
            else
            {
                pdebug(1,"not found\n");
                print "\nunmatched reference in file:\n$file\n";
                findline($file,$line);
                print"\ncouldn't find file:\n       $searchfile\nreferenced as:\n$line\n";


            }
        }
```

This is the relevant part of my code so far. Not shown is the part where I'm iterating through the directory structure to identify every file wich has to be checked.
Used subs not in code not shown here:

pdebug: prints out debugtext

findline: expects filename and a string to search for, prints out the linenumber(s) where it is found

buildpath: each filetype belongs to a subdirectory (i.e. .wav in audio/effects, .tga in textures), buildpath examines a filename and returns a complete path

Can someone get me into the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to have only one regex:

```
while (<$filehandle>)
{
   my @filenames = /(?<=")(?:\w+\/)*\w+[.]\w+(?:")/g;
   say join("$_\n", @filename) if @filename > 0;
}
```

See here for the regexp:
https://regex101.com/r/bA4oZ7/1

The 'x' modificator allow to write a multiline regex and add some comments here the explanation of your regex (available here: https://regex101.com/r/bA4oZ7/3)

```
my $re qr/(?<=") # A filename is after a double quote char
(?:[^"\/]+\/)+   # the path is one or more words separated with a slash
[^"\/]+          # The filename (not the path) can be anything but a double quote char and a slash
[.]\w+           # The extension cannot have space and have the form of .foobar
(?:")            # A filename end with a double quote char
/gx;

...
my @filenames = /$re/g;
```

Comment: This is excellent! But it bails out on 
id = "vehicle/train/BR 78_Body.grp",
Can you tell me why it does this?

Comment: It's because you have a space in your filename. Try with this: https://regex101.com/r/bA4oZ7/2